# Generate token after login nodejs API

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am creating an API using nodejs and express.  I need to provide local username/password authentication.  I may need to provide additional authentication in the future so I am using passportjs as it seems the most flexible/plug-able.

The API will be used by a web application as well as a mobile application.  Instead of having to pass the username/password with every single api request I was thinking I could let the user login and provide the client with a token.  The client can store the token and provide that on each api request.

I have looked at using JWT tokens ie, http://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/securing-node-js-restful-services-with-jwt-tokens/.  However I am not really sure how to create a secure token with JWT.  I have read that using the username in a token is a bad idea.  Has anyone use JWT in node to create tokens.  Got an example?

Any other modules for node that I can take a look at for token generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was already built into nodes crypto pacakge.

http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback

Answer (score 5):

[node-uuid](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid) is the module you are looking for. I use it to authenticate the users and any task that requires a random and unique identifier. Encoding the credentials in the token is generally a bad idea.